# nautilus items aren't snapped to grid

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gui, filemanager

Recently I did a `nautilus` upgrade and it became a pile of mess:

[image: mess]
I tried downgrading but that didn't work.

Nautilus version 3.26.0, using GNOME-shell.

**Update1**: Seems like `pcmanfm-gtk3` worked fine. `nemo` didn't, however.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. This one is somehow solved(possibly with another update). But new issues has arisen. File names are on top of each other, clicking an icon has a weird behavior... I think some other library update triggered the issues.  Thunar file manager has also started to look weird.  Couldn't find a relevant bug report yet.

Comment: @Hckr if they overlap, go to Preferences and untick whatever's under the Experimental section (new view something).